# Oracle "partition" a table at each new value

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have an Oracle table I need to "partition" :I use the terme loosely, I just need to detect groups and would like to display the group through a `SELECT`. Here's an example that might serve as a sample data (the four columns):

```
ID | Ref | Rank | Partition_group (only available for the 1st member)
1  | 1   | 1    | 1_A
2  | 1   | 2    | (null)
3  | 1   | 3    | 1_B
4  | 2   | 1    | (null)
5  | 2   | 2    | 2_A
...
```

It is sorted (the sort key would be the 'Ref' and a creation date). What I would need here, is to extract three groups:

- IDs 1 and 2
- ID 3
- ID 5
  What happens with ID 4 is not really important: it may be in its own group, or with the ID 5.

Two IDS should be in the same group if they have the same 'Ref' and if there hasn't been any 'Partition_group' change. In other words, at each change of 'Ref' or (logical or) 'Partition_group', I need to detect a new group. For instance, we could return something like that:

```
ID | Ref | Rank | Partition_group | Group
1  | 1   | 1    | 1_A             | 1_A
2  | 1   | 2    | (null)          | 1_A
3  | 1   | 3    | 1_B             | 1_B
4  | 2   | 1    | (null)          | (null) (or 2_A)
5  | 2   | 2    | 2_A             | 2_A
...
```

I thought about writing a function or something, but it appears I don't have the rights to do so (yeah...) so I have to use plain Oracle SQL (11g).
I've been looking at `CONNECT BY` and `OVER` (analytical functions) but they don't seem to do the trick.

Has anyone been faced to such a problem? How would you resolve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use a case statement when generating the group name, ie. to convert id=2 to id=1, id=4 to id=5 etc. However, you've given us the expected output, but no sample input data - it would be helpful if you could update your question to include that. Unless the sample_data is the first 3 columns in the expected output?

Comment: The example I gave was the sample data actually. The four columns are. Actually, the third column (rank) is a dense rank() over(partition by ref order by creationdate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the input data is the first four columns, how about something like:

```
with sample_data as (select 1 id, 1 ref, 1 rank, '1_A' ptn_group from dual union all
                     select 2 id, 1 ref, 2 rank, null ptn_group from dual union all
                     select 3 id, 1 ref, 3 rank, '1_B' ptn_group from dual union all
                     select 4 id, 2 ref, 1 rank, null ptn_group from dual union all
                     select 5 id, 2 ref, 2 rank, '2_A' ptn_group from dual)
select id,
       ref,
       rank,
       ptn_group,
       last_value(ptn_group ignore nulls) over (partition by ref order by rank, id) grp1,
       case when last_value(ptn_group ignore nulls) over (partition by ref order by rank, id) is null then
                 first_value(ptn_group ignore nulls) over (partition by ref order by rank, id rows between current row and unbounded following)
            else last_value(ptn_group ignore nulls) over (partition by ref order by rank, id)
       end grp2
from   sample_data;

        ID        REF       RANK PTN_GROUP GRP1 GRP2
---------- ---------- ---------- --------- ---- ----
         1          1          1 1_A       1_A  1_A 
         2          1          2           1_A  1_A 
         3          1          3 1_B       1_B  1_B 
         4          2          1                2_A 
         5          2          2 2_A       2_A  2_A
```

I've given you two options to generate the grp, based on how you want to deal with rows where the first rows of the ptn_group are null - leave them null or pick up the first non-null value in the group.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. Nonetheless, your solution doesn't seem to put the ID 2 in the group 1_A. The example output I proposed really is what I need.:/

Comment: Ah right; I had it as just the first 3 cold. Will revisit this when I'm back in the office after lunch.

Comment: Taking the input data as the first 4 cols makes things much easier *{:-) Basically the `LAST_VALUE()` analytic function is your friend - possibly in conjunction with `FIRST_VALUE()`.

Comment: Genius. Thanks you very much. I hope I'll get a 15 reputation someday so the upvote I gave you will be taken in acount.